# converting a if condition into function with dynamic multiplying number

Tags: javascript, math

I have a drop down menu, which has years listed. Upon selecting a year. The value is calculated based on months in the choose year, like if someone choose 5 years, then *5*12 - months in 5 years* , that value then get divided by a certain amount.My loop works fine but if i do each if condition for a dropdown for like 8 years, its 8 loop and in each loop, the amount of months is increased and calculation happen. is there a simple way to do this, instead of me looping it again and again, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovdcd89m/1/) here.

```
var yr = document.getElementById("year");
var selected = yr.options[yr.selectedIndex].value;
if(selected == 10){
    months = 12 * 10;
    amount = 68/months;
    alert(amount)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure loop is the right term to use here. Could you explain what you mean by loop? Are you referring to the `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need all those ifs, you can do as follows:

```
var yr = document.getElementById("year");
var selected = yr.options[yr.selectedIndex].value;

months = 12 * parseInt(selected);
amount = 68/months;
alert(amount);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ovdcd89m/2/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood your problem right, but I think this is probably what you're trying to accomplish:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#year').change(function(){
        var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
        year = parseInt(year);
        alert( 68/(12*year) );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="year">Year</label>
<select id="year">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10" selected>10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to convert the value from the option to a number before you can do the math. For any selected value, try:

```
months = 12 * parseInt(selected, 10);
amount = 68/months;
alert(amount);
```